# JGit allows Push to update checked out branch

Tags: git, push, jgit

When I try to PUSH into checked out branch on remote I am getting an error with GIT BASH and success when using JGIT. As a result I end up with successful PUSH (I can see commit ) and old version of the branch being staged... How do I fix that. I want JGIT to fail while updating checked out branch. The code is very straightforward:
git.push().setCredentialsProvider(cp).call();

Comment: This sounds like a bug/omission in the implementation of JGit push(), at least I don't see any option to enable this behavior. Maybe you can report this as bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/ to the developers of JGit can take a look?

Comment: Thank you. I also didn't find any option in push. Thinking about doing some preprocessing to avoid that in a meanwhile.

Comment: I contacted eclipse and got the following answer:"JGit does not yet implement all the receive.* git configs. In particular it does not implement receive.denyCurrentBranch and receive.denyDeleteCurrent."